# Is there a current way to distribute AWS Quicksight Dashboard alerts?

Tags: amazon-web-services, slack-api, amazon-quicksight, alerts

Is there a current way to configure to whom the alerts from a QuickSight dashboard can be sent to?

I'm looking for a way to send the alerts to persons of contact and not just myself. Anything like a DL email list, slack channel, or individual emails would work.

I dont see the dashboard alerts being sent to Cloudwatch or anything like that which seems very very limitting. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

We ran into this issue as well.  From my experience, I have not been able to sign up other users (be it Admins, Authors or Readers) for alerts.  A couple workarounds:

1. Instruct the user(s) who you would like to get alerts how to set the alerts up on their own account.
2. Set up an email forwarding that will catch any alerts in your inbox and send them to the desired parties.

Definitely should be a feature in the future to sign others up.

Comment: Ah yeah, i thought so. Thanks for the tips!. Hopefully it becomes a feature soon.